# Qual è la differenza tra "posso farla" and "ce la faccio"

Tags: difference

1. posso farla
2. ce la faccio

Is there a difference between these two phrases or do they both mean "I can do it"?

Is one more common than the other?

Grazie!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two equivalent ways of saying “I can do it” – in a generic way, with the meaning of “I'll manage” – are *ce la posso fare* and *posso farcela*.

*Ce la faccio* denotes more confidence: “I am doing it”, “I'm almost there”, more or less.

Finally, *posso farla* would just mean “I can do [this particular thing]”, as in answering to a question like «*Puoi fare l'ultima parte?*» (Can you do the last part?).

Answer (score 2):

I guess in your first sentence you mean "Posso farcela". In this case we can say both sentences have the same meaning... however saying "Ce la faccio" is a slightly stronger and more confident statement than "Posso farcela".