# Understanding "ce la" in "ce la faccio" and other similar expressions

Tags: meaning, pronouns, particles

Can someone explain why we are using "ce" in "ce la faccio", for example? Why isn't it enough to use "la faccio"? I think it should be that way since "la" indicates "it".
Would love to understand the use of "ce" more profoundly.

Comment: Have you seen these similar questions? [[1](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/qual-%c3%a8-la-differenza-tra-posso-farla-and-ce-la-faccio)] and [[2](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/non-ce-la-fai-proprio-a-smettere-vero-meaning)]

Comment: Yes but they did not address why "ce" is in use. Another example is "ce l'hai", not necessarily "farcela". Why "ce"? And how to memorise or know when to use it?

Comment: @LoveIsHere: Do you mean "ce" instead of "ci"? Or simply why is this pronominal particle in use in these expressions?

Comment: Why do we use ce/ci + lo/li if it seems like they have the same meaning?

Comment: Ce = it. Lo = it.

Comment: @LoveIsHere:  "Farcela" and "avercela" (by the way, it's "la" and not "lo") are examples of what are called "verbi pronominali", which are part of the so called ["verbi polirematici"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-polirematiche_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), something which in some sense is similar to English phrasal verbs: these are crystallised espressions that you have to memorise and sometimes it's very difficult to explain the meaning of their constituents.

Comment: @Charo. Ok  Thank you. I will read more about it. It is good to know it is more of a phrase and not very explainable...

Comment: The use of "ce" can be hard to understand for a foreigner because it can be used both as a "proper" pronoun and as part of a pronominal verbs. For example, depending on context, "ce l'hai" can mean "you have it" (e.g. "mi serve un cacciavite, ce l'hai?" = "I need a screwdriver; do you have it?") or "you are mad at someone" ("Ti ho sentito urlare, con chi ce l'hai?" = "I heard you shouting; to whom are you mad?"). Similarly, "ce la fai" can mean both "you make it to/for us" or "you succeed in something".

Answer (score 1):

The clitic pronoun *ci* carries the “there” meaning, which implies the directionality towards which the action is directed. The phrase *ce la faccio* doesn’t carry the meaning of *la faccio* —i. e. *farla*— by itself, since the verb *farcela* was grammaticalized, just like pronominal verbs like *divertirsi*. It was not inherited from Latin, but chances are that its “directionality” was derived from Neapolitan. Same situation happens with *avercela* [con qc], which is entirely *grammaticalized* and, thus, it is not divisible or cannot be rephrased simply as *averla* [con qc].

Grammaticalized pronominal verbs occurred, too, in Spanish, for instance: *pasarla* [adv.], whose meaning is absolutely different to that of *pasar*.